# Formula insertion In Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I Have a sheet where i want to insert this formula (**=D5*60*8*L1**) in one of the cell. I just want L1 Value to be constant. How to go About it?

Pls revert back if question is not clear and seems little ambiguous to you.

Comment: Change your formula to `=D5*60*8*L$1` (note the dollar sign `$`) to hold the row number (1) constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use below formula:

```
=D5*60*8*L$1
```

Note: Two types of cell references exists: **relative** and **absolute**. Relative and absolute references behave differently when copied and filled to other cells. Relative references change when a formula is copied to another cell. Absolute references, on the other hand, remain constant, no matter where they are copied.

Check this Microsoft Tutorial on the same : http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-HP010342940.aspx

Comment: Thanks for tutorial suggestion. Anyway your answer helped.